# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0

Tags: crystal-reports

I am testing a ASP.NET program.  When I launch the program in a Test-PC (Windows 10 Professional with .NET Framework 4.8), I get this error message:

> "Could not load file or assembly
> 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...' or one of its dependencis. The
> system cannot find the file specified."

The program was written in an very old Visual Studio for .NET Framework 1.1. targeting Windows-XP 32-bit. I have upgraded everything to Visual Studio 2017 for .NET Framework 4.8 targeting Windows-10, again for 32-bit platform. Everything works including the reports when I run the program in Visual Studio 2017 in my PC. Then I also upgrade the Setup program to install this program in a PC with Windows-10 Professional -- let call it Test-PC.  I use the Test-PC to test the deployment process. The Test-PC has both the server-part of the program (IIS) and the client-part of the program (the program that I am testing). I run the Setup program to install the client program without any problem. But when I launch the program (client part), I get that error message mentioned above.

I was not the original developer. There were two previous developers before it was handed over to me. Therefore, I am not familiar with this program.

In the "References" of the Visual Studio project of the client part of the program, I see that it is referring to CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll that is in C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\2.8\managed folder.  That has the version 10.5.3700.0 that the error message refers to. And all of them are dated 2007.

But when I examine the Visual Studio project for creating the Setup program, I see that it has the following components:

- Crystal_Database_Access2003.msm
- Crystal_Database_Access2003_enu.msm
- Crystal_Managed2003.msm
- Crystal_regwiz2003.msm
- msmask32_X86.msm
- msmask32_X86_ENU.msm
- VC_User_CRT71_RTL_X86_---.msm

All of them are in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules folder.  Almost all of them are dated 2003 (one is from 2002).  I cannot tell which version they are.  But based on the date on the files, I have a feeling that they are older than the one that the client part of the program is referring to. May be version 1.0?

Seem like this is a mismatch. But how can I update the Visual Studio project for making the Setup program to ask it to install the correct version of Crystal Reports?

Please help.  Thanks.

JayC

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by downloading the 13.0.22 (SP 22) version of Crystal Report from this web page:
[Downloads for SAP Crystal Report](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html)

I downloaded the "CR for Visual Studio SP22 install package" and installed it in my computer to be used with Visual Studio.  The installation program mentioned something about installing the 64-bit run-time because my O/S is 64-bit.  I was a bit hesitate because my program is built for 32-bit.  I said Yes to install the 64-bit run time anyway.  When I opened my project in Visual Studio 2017, it automatically helped me to convert my project file to use the new 13.0.22 verison to replace the 10.5.3700.0 version.  I rebuilt the project to get an updated EXE/DLL files.  And my program ran fine in Visual Studio.

Then I downloaded the "CR for Visual Studio SP22 Merge Modules 32-bit" ZIP file (because my program is in 32-bit).  I extracted the CRRuntime_13_0_22.msm and CRRruntime_maps_13_0_22.msm from the ZIP file.  I modified the project file for the Setup program to ask it to use those two files (to replace those 4 old Crystal Reports files).

With the same version of Crystal Reports used in both Visual Studio and Setup program.  My program runs fine in the Test-PC.

Please note that I had to use 13.0.22, not 13.0.18 or 13.0.19 because those 2 versions gave me error when I ran my installation program in Test-PC.

JayC